# javascript canvas function not working without an alert

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, alert

I'm doing some demo web pages as part of a portfolio to show potential employers.
One page is the simulation of a plasma arc in a 'plasma ball' which then rotates to view the 'arc' through 360 degrees.
The redraw of the arc through each of the rotations ONLY works if I put an 'alert' after each redraw and then cancel the alerts when the script runs. Without the alert, nothing happens.

Does anyone have an explanation/solution for this? Here's the redraw function:

```
function reDraw(yAngle) //work in progress - redraw the arc through 360 degrees to see the path
{
   var xCs;
   var yCs;

   for(degrees=10; degrees<360; degrees+=1)//spin sphere through 360 degrees
   {   

      context1 = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");

      context1.clearRect(0,0,600,600);

      radialGrad(1,'canvas1',300,300,300,300,300,0,0,1,colour1,colour2,0,0,600,600);

      firstMove=true;

      for(moves=0; moves<axisMove; moves++)
      {
         if(firstMove)//start at centre of sphere for each re-draw
         {
            xCs=300;
            yCs=300;
            firstMove=false;         
         }

         context1.beginPath();

         context1.moveTo(xCs,yCs);         

         spinAngle=(degrees/180*Math.PI);

         //we are spinning in the X-Z plane so resolve X-Z moves only - retrieve each positive or negative move from the axis move arrays

         xCs=xCs+(zCStep[moves]*Math.sin(spinAngle))+(xCStep[moves]*Math.cos(spinAngle));

         yCs=yCs+yCStep[moves];

         context1.lineTo(xCs,yCs);

         context1.shadowBlur=2;
         context1.shadowColor="grey";

         context1.strokeStyle="white";
         context1.stroke();

      }
      alert();   
   }

}
```

Comment: The framerate is too fast, try using `settimeout` to give an amount of time to display each frame

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh: almost, it's the same 'problem' as with (non html5) progress bars: there is no redraw (which is *almost* the same as 'frame rate to high').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to their (historically) single-threaded nature, Webbrowsers re-draw content when a (javascript) function(handler) *ends* (same problem with progress bars, ajax-loading gif, etc).
So, even when one iteration of your loop would take a full second (resulting in 1FPS), the canvas still wouldn't redraw (same goes for the rest of the page's content) until your javascript ends.

Small side note: one of the biggest advantages of HTML5 web-workers is that they run in their own thread so they don't 'block the browser'.

The (historically) common solution to the above problems is to use a timer (`setInterval` seems best for your particular case, or `setTimeout`) in order to have the browser redraw the content (in this case the canvas-element).

**EDIT:**
Stefano Ortisi reminded me in his comment below about `requestAnimationFrame` and provided an excellent link: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
Basically it's main reason for existence is so we don't need to keep using the same timers, having a browser-optimised implementation (vs timers) and ideally to use it together with webworkers (yay, extra thread).

At first this API was quite a 'living' specification (which is why I forgot about it), but by now the dust seems to have settled enough to create a nice polyfill (see above link).
I agree that anno dec. 2013 this is a better solution then defining your own timer, since "if you’re running the animation loop in a tab that’s not visible, the browser won’t keep it running, which means less CPU, GPU, and memory usage, leading to much longer battery life."

Comment: worth checking requestAnimationFrame as well http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: @StefanoOrtisi: that *IS a good comment* (thx), but I'd like to add that it still needs a polyfill, however, it is cleaner and better then whipping up your own, since it can pause in unused tabs, *that is something I highly value*!!! Want me to add it to the answer for future readers?

Comment: @GitaarLAB - so why is each redraw happening with the 'alert' in the code? settimeout/setinterval calls are being ignored when I use them inside the 'redraw' function.

Comment: The alert is a 'host' method, and the 'host' in a browser is usually 'window' (hence window.alert()). Some browsers give you the option to 'cancel' (as you called it) multiple alerts, so most probably the javascript still 'pauses' (I call an alert a poor-mans-break-point for good reasons...) and hands over control to the host (aka browser in this case) requesting to pop-up the alert-window. You should try setup an interval that calls a function that draws *one* frame per function call (and you'd need to store some state to know where you are in your animation).

Comment: @GitaarLAB - how would you code a 'setTimeout/setInterval' pause into my code? Nothing I try seems to work!

Comment: Or how do I use the 'requestAnimationFrame' ? I don't understand it

Comment: Uhmm, shouldn't you know (at least) timers, since this is "part of a portfolio to show potential employers" ? As I wrote in my above comment: "try setup an interval that calls a function that draws one frame per function call (and you'd need to store some state to know where you are in your animation)". Also you might want to search a couple of minutes here on SO to find loads of examples and explanations about timers. If that doesn't help, I think it is better to ask a new question (and leave this (in my opinion) *good* question as is). The Paul Irish link has working examples to!

Comment: Thank you for your welcome! I very much appreciate your answers. I'm teaching myself javascript - I come from a different IT background - to move into (web/software) development. Uhmm.... I do understand timers but as I said, every 'setTimeout/setInterval call I try is ignored. If I get this thing working I'll post my solution. Thanks again :-)

Comment: I wanted to give it a go (break your 2 loops), but there is not enough code to work with (what is: colour1, colour2, axisMove, zCStep, xCStep, yCStep?). Also (as I don't understand it's use) I would replace `firstMove=true;` simply with: `xCs=300; yCs=300;` (and remove it's corresponding if-block). Also, javascript only has function-scope, *no* block-scope, so you were leaking: degrees, moves, spinAngle, context1. And, accessing dom and getting canvas every outerloop is a waste of ops.

Comment: it's working now - got distracted watching T'Pol on Startrek - used a setInterval call from the first random arc function and incremented (global) 'degrees' variable in the redraw function. Thanks. PS - whereabouts in the world are you, as a matter of interest?

Comment: how can I send the code? have you an email address or can I do it on this forum?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net is the most used website on SO when talking about javascript since it is very simple to fiddle around in javascript, go check it out!

Comment: I set up a user account on jsfiddle and sent you the htm file

Comment: got the mail + attachment. Looks good so far. If you have got an account and you click the `save`-button, then you'll see the addresses update to a new url in the form of `jsfiddle.net/xxxxx/` or `jsfiddle.net/username/xxxxx/` when you are logged-on. So you can share the link to the jsfiddle yourself if you want.

Answer (score 0):

By its definition the `<canvas>` element uses bitmap buffer. You can think about the `<canvas>` as of `<img>` with modifiable bitmap.

Script draws in that bitmap (but not on the screen). 
And browser renders that bitmap when it has the chance.

To give the browser a chance to draw your bitmap at some step you should yield execution from your script to the browser in some way: call `alert()`, setTimeout/Interval or do your drawing in animation frames ( `requestAnimationFrame` ).

`requestAnimationFrame` is pretty much a request to redraw the browser view that will happen after next 16ms (60 fps max in browsers) or so.

Comment: Could you *please* share a link to a reference/source of those 16 ms ? I know of personal testing that 20ms is usually pushing the limits and 30ms is for most *other* tasks (like waiting for a new (i)frame) my ideal cross-browser value

Comment: The first thing I tried was setTimeout and setInterval - no joy. I don't understand the requestAnimationFrame code yet but I'll give it a go.

Comment: I found the link, it was in the same paul irish article that stefano linked to (see my answer). (side-note: LOL, I never knew the 30 ms I found *was* due to a bug in firefox, so now I'll still use that for crossbrowser compatibility)

Comment: @GitaarLAB, 60 fps is more platform limitation than browser one. E.g. in Windows WM_PAINT normally comes 60 times per second, Mac also has similar cap. It simply makes no sense to redraw faster than that. Human eye will not catch more frequent changes.

Comment: 72 to 75 hz (flicker free), yet 60hz on 'slow' flatscreens (so ultimately 80FPS @ 80HZ is 'perfect' to the human eye). But I get the point :) THX!